# Console open pcturebox with images

Tags: c#

How to launch picturebox with console? and the picturebox exit but the console still stay in background?

```
namespace DisplayImage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

   PictureBox p =new PictureBox();
    p.ImageLocation = "1.jpg"
    p.Location = new Point(100, 75);
        }
    }
}
```

it got error. is it picture box only avaiable in windows form?

Comment: Picturebox is a winforms control, even in winforms you'd have to add the control to the form (as it stand now you only create it not add it) in forms it'd be something like `this.Controls.Add(p);`

Comment: @EpicKip is it possible to open picturebox when beginning and exit but leave a console in background?

Comment: Make a winforms project with just a picturebox and no border on the form (so picturebox is full form size) then open the form from the console code and make it close after x seconds (add some logic).

Comment: `it got error.` What error did you get? Was it compile time? Run time?

Comment: @EpicKip thats what i thinking. but i see top exe it can do such task. them play with thread. like 2 app run 1 app.

Comment: @mjwills i just copy the code from button event. i think the problem is event trigger when load. and thats code execute for say 3 second and continue execute other code.

Answer (score 0):

`PictureBox` class only available for Windows Forms - ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

PictureBox is a Window control (GUI element) - it is available only when you add reference to System.Windows.Forms.
Moreover even if you add that assembly, your above code will not work because PictureBox is just a control, it needs to be put into a container (Form) for it to display.

I guess you are trying to create a Picture Viewer or something from console. May be there is a better way of doing what you need.

Do you want to pass the path to image/picture as command line argument to console app and that app should launch? Elaborate on what you want to achieve and may be we can advice better.

Comment: i add reference to windows.form. its mean i can launch picturebox in console right? and how achieve this. the event is its top code before other code exec.

Comment: yeah something like picture viewer but no button control. its just display 3 seconds and exit. and leave in background as console.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SampleViewer
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string imagePath = args[0];

            Form sampleForm = new Form();
            PictureBox pctBox = new PictureBox();
            pctBox.ImageLocation = imagePath;
            pctBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            sampleForm.Controls.Add(pctBox);
            sampleForm.ShowDialog();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This should help you show the image. You will have to write additional logic to hide the form after 3 seconds.